# Can a product of 4 consecutive natural numbers end in 116

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

So i was given this question with two parts:

(a) Prove that the product of two consecutive even numbers is always
divisible by 8.

(b) Can a product of 4 consecutive natural numbers end in 116?

For part (a) here is my solution

Let the first even number be $2n$. The second will be $2n + 2$.

$$2n(2n + 2)$$

$$= 4n^2 + 4n$$

$$= 4(n^2 + n)$$

$$= 4n(n + 1)$$

If n is even:

$$= 4(2k)(n + 1)$$

$$= 8k(n + 1)$$

This is divisible by 8.

If n is odd

$$= 4(2k + 1)(2k + 1 + 1)$$ 
$$= 4(2k + 1)(2k + 2)$$ 
$$= 4(2k + 1)2(k + 1)$$ 
$$= 8(2k + 1)(k + 1)$$

This is divisible by 8

How do you do part (b)?

Comment: You're missing the proof for the case $n$ is odd. For part b: is $116$ divisible by $8$?

Comment: Hint for b:  Is $1000*k + 116$ divisible by 8?  (I think vadim123 made a typo).  Is n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3) divisible by 8?

Comment: @egreg fixed it

Answer (score 4):

I recognize the merit of the exercise. But it could be mentioned that the product of four consecutive natural numbers ends in 0 or in 4. The latter occurs when the first of the four numbers ends in 1 or 6.

Answer (score 2):

Part a: you are forgetting that $n$ could be odd.

Part b: among four consecutive numbers you surely find two consecutive even numbers. If the product can be written $p=1000x+116$, note that $1000$ is divisible by $8$ and, by part a, $p$ is divisible by $8$. So…

Comment: I do not get how $p = 1000x + 116$ solves it

Comment: @Zero: Is $1000$ divisible by $8$? Is $116$ divisible by $8$? And therefore: Is $1000x+116$ divisible by $8$?

Comment: @TonyK so since 116 is not divisible by 8 So a product of 4 consecutive natural numbers end in 116 is not true?

Comment: @Zero: Correct!

Comment: One of the even numbers is divisible by 4 (or a higher power of 2), the other just by 2. Had to squint to see it.